# Configure Magento to use Elasticsearch for Magento ver. 2.2.4 Open Source

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement Elasticsearch to my Magento ver. 2.2.4 Open Source web store.

I followed this [guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/elasticsearch/configure-magento.html) step by step until I hit a snag where "Elasticsearch" is not available in the admin configuration area.

> From the Search Engine list, click Elasticsearch or Elasticsearch 5.0+ as the following figure shows. (The Elasticsearch 5.0+ option is not available for Magento 2.1.)

The option for Elasticsearch is missing and the only available search engine is MySQL.
[image: Elasticsearch option missing]

I ran `composer update` thinking it might be the code base missing some files but after successfully accomplishing the composer update, the issue still persist.

Should the "Elasticsearch" Search Engine option be available in the configuration out of the box for this version of Magento? Is this option available for anyone?

Comment: this option is available in Enterprise version only, for community you need to install  extension.

Comment: upgrade to 2.3.3 opensource you will find the ElasticSearch Option.   **Elasticsearch 6.0+ (Recommended) —For the best performance, we recommend that you use the latest version of Elasticsearch 6.0+**
 https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/search-elasticsearch.html